# Range function of 4 variables (presumably using inequalities)

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am dealing with the following exercise:
"If $x,y,z,t>0$,find all the possible values of the function $H(x,y,z,t)$, where $H(x,y,z,t)=\frac{x}{x+y+t}+\frac{y}{x+y+z}+\frac{z}{y+z+t}+\frac{t}{x+z+t}$." Obviously all the values of $H$ are positive and, with regard to the maximum value, I considered using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality since it was useful to me in other similar problems but in this case I don't know how. I tried taking $a=(\frac{x}{x+y+t},\frac{y}{x+y+z},\frac{z}{y+z+t},\frac{t}{x+z+t})$ and $b=(1,1,1,1)$ so that the dot product of $a$ and $b$ is $H$; with an eye to stating that $H \leq 2||a||$ but I haven't been able to determine $||a||$. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Revising some time later this problem, I think I have found a way to solve it. The only thing that remains is bounding $||a||=\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{(x+y+t)^2}+\frac{y^2}{(y+x+z)^2}+\frac{z^2}{(z+y+t)^2}}$. At this point one can state that:
$\frac{x^2}{(x+y+t)^2} < \frac{x^2}{x^2}=1$ because $f(x)=x^2$ is a
strictly increasing function $\forall x>0$. So, as we are working with positive numbers, $(x+y+t)^2>x^2$, which implies $\frac{x^2}{(x+y+t)^2} < \frac{x^2}{x^2}$. In this way,$\frac{x^2}{(x+y+t)^2}<1$.
Analogously for the other two other addends involved in $||a||$, we deduce that $\frac{y^2}{(y+x+z)^2}<1$ and $\frac{z^2}{(z+y+t)^2}<1$. So, $\frac{x^2}{(x+y+t)^2}+\frac{y^2}{(y+x+z)^2}+\frac{z^2}{(z+y+t)^2}<3$ and, as $f(x)=\sqrt(x)$ is a stricly increasing function for positive values,$||a||=\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{(x+y+t)^2}+\frac{y^2}{(y+x+z)^2}+\frac{z^2}{(z+y+t)^2}}<\sqrt(3)$.

As a result, $|H(x,y,z,t)|<2\sqrt3$, so $H(x,y,z,t) \in (-2\sqrt3,2\sqrt3)$